# Command Button Block

Tags: html

```
  *<af:commandButton text="#{res['pci.buttons.save']}"
                          blocking="true"
                          disabled="#{claimFileDetailAddBean.buttonsDisabled "}    
                          action="#{claimFileDetailAddBean.save}"/>*
```

### I use this html. I want; button block proceed until the end of action. How is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to dynamically disable / enable your button?
In that case you can use [javascript DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp)
You can use the tag object.disabled=true to disable and object.disabled=true to disable.
All you have to do is making a function for it.

BTW: next time be more specific in your questions.

Comment: I can't use javascript because; action and onclick tag don't work at teh same time on ADF. I want button blocked when action perform operations at bean. After end the operations insight blocking.

Comment: Can you be more specific (post some code what you've already and things you've tried?